# textBox is not assigning values to my properties

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have some textbox and combobox in my code, you write some data on them, and the idea is to keep that data in some properties from some classes previously initialized.

ComboBox just works fine, and the data is sent to the database withh no problem, but textbox no :(

I show part of the code

```
        ctlCrpVhcPrs.ClvCrp = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox4.SelectedValue);
        ctlCrpVhcPrs.ClvVhc = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedValue);
        ctlCrpVhcPrs.ClvPrs = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox2.SelectedValue);
        ctlCrpVhcPrs.ClvMnc = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox3.SelectedValue);
        ctlCrpVhcPrs.RgnZna = textBox2.Text;
        ctlCrpVhcPrs.ClvZna = textBox3.Text;
        ctlCrpVhcPrs.ClvSct = textBox4.Text;
        ctlCrpVhcPrs.EstVhc = textBox5.Text;
```

If I debug the code, when i reach textbox3, for example, I check the value for textbox2.Text and is "somedata", and for ctlCrpVhcPrs.RgnZna is ""

Ideas, please?

Comment: How are you putting the values back as being set?

Comment: On what event or method are you using the above code?

Answer (score -1):

I need more detail of your code. For now try these ways:

```
ctlCrpVhcPrs.RgnZna = textBox2.Text.ToString();

//or

string str=textBox2.Text;
ctlCrpVhcPrs.RgnZna = str;
```